# Using layout as a button

Tags: android, button, layout

I was trying to make a custom button in Android that contains more than one components, to put it straight forward what button contains in form of a layout, here it is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:background="@drawable/button1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:background="@drawable/button4"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sub-description"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Question: how to use this as a button in an Activity with all sort of button pressed and focused customisation? 
(till now all i have worked around is only with this UI file XML)

Comment: A better option would be to include the images in the textviews. A technique known as compund drawables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options in XML or Code.

XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:background="@drawable/button4"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sub-description"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button5" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

In code .java use:

```
LinearLayout.setClickable(true);
```

And remember in both cases use onClick like a simple button.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the LinearLayout to clickable. You can either do this in the XML with

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Or in code with

```
yourLinearLayout.setClickable(true);


yourLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // DO STUFF!
                }
            }
        );
```

Cheers!